# If $f$ and $g$ are integrable functions on $I=[a,b]$ and if $h(x):=\inf(f(x), g(x))$ for all $x \in I$, prove that $h$ is integrable at $I$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f$ and $g$ are integrable functions on $I=[a,b]$ and if $h(x):=\inf(f(x), g(x))$ for all $x \in I$, prove that $h$ is integrable at $I$.

By Riemann integrability

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? What have you tried? What definition(s) of integrability on $I$ are you using?

Comment: by Riemann´s integrability

Comment: There are several equivalent definitions of Riemann integrability. Which one(s) do you know?

Comment: when $L(f)=U(f)$ or $\lim_{n \to \infty} U(P;f)-L(P;f)=0$. I´m just learning the first definition of Riemann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Strategy Considerations.**  The general strategy for proving Riemann integrability is to refer to the fundamental inequality
$$\ldots\leq L(P,h)\ldots\leq U(P,h)\leq\ldots$$
where the $\ldots$ are other known quantities with known relations/estimates that can be used in order to conclude $U(P,h)-L(P,h)\leq\epsilon.$  Note that (1) below represents an initial such a pair of quantities with a known relation/estimate.  The challenge is usually to obtain some upper or lower bound on one end of the inequality, and to do this usually requires the construction of a special partition which takes advantage of the properties of the function in question.  The proof below illustrates this strategy.

---

**Solution.**  Choose $\epsilon>0$ and let $P_{\epsilon}=\{x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\}\subset I$ be a partition of $I$ so that
$$\begin{align*}(1)&&U(P_{\epsilon},f)-L(P_{\epsilon},f)\leq\epsilon&&\text{and}&&U(P_{\epsilon},g)-L(P_{\epsilon},g)\leq\epsilon\end{align*}$$
and let $P\supset P_{\epsilon}$ be any refinement of $P_{\epsilon}.$  Define
$$\begin{align*}m^{h}_{i}:=\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}h(x)&&M^{h}_{i}:=\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}h(x)&&(i=1,\ldots,n).\end{align*}$$
Let $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ be sub-partitions of $P$ so that on $P_{1}$ $m^{h}_{i}=m^{f}_{i}$ and on $P_{2}$ $m^{h}_{i}=m^{g}_{i}.$  Let $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ be the respective index sets of $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ and define respectively
$$\sum_{i\in I_{1}}m^{f}_{i}\Delta x_{i}+\sum_{i\in I_{2}}m^{g}_{i}\Delta x_{i}:=s_{1}+s_{2}$$
and
$$\sum_{i\in I_{1}}M^{f}_{i}\Delta x_{i}+\sum_{i\in I_{2}}M^{g}_{i}\Delta x_{i}:=S_{1}+S_{2}.$$

The definition of $h$ then implies
$$s_{1}+s_{2}=L(P,h)\leq L(P,f),L(P,g)\leq U(P,h)\leq S_{1}+S_{2}\leq U(P,f),U(P,g).$$

However, by (1)
$$(S_{1}+S_{2})-(s_{1}+s_{2})=(S_{1}-s_{1})+(S_{2}-s_{2})\leq2\epsilon,$$
hence
$$|U(P,h)-L(P,h)|\leq2\epsilon.$$

This proves $h$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: THANK YOU¡¡, But How can we give two subpartitions?? and what are their index sets?? could you explain me a little bit that part??

Comment: $P=\{x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\}$.  It could be that, say, $P_{1}=\{x_{0},x_{3},x_{5},x_{11},\ldots,x_{n-1}\}$ and $P_{2}=\{x_{1},x_{2},x_{4},\ldots,x_{n}\}$.  Then $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are partitions of $I$ and they are sub-partitions of $P$ in the sense that $P=P_{1}\cup P_{2}$.  The index sets in this example are $I_{1}=\{0,3,5,11,\ldots,n-1\}$ and $I_{2}=\{1,2,4,\ldots,n\}.$  The manner in which the sub-partitions are obtained depend on $f$ and $g$ in accordance to the construction in the solution above.  Perhaps the notation of $I_{j}$ is confusing-it has nothing to do with the interval $I$

Comment: All Right, i´ve got confused thinking that the Index sets were related to $I$